# Why won't my toy motor turn when pressure is applied to the sides?

Tags: motor, dc, dc-motor

I have a toy DC motor. It's one of those cheap (~$1) ones from eBay.

Normally, when I provide power to it, it turns.

However, if I hold the metal cage very firmly, it won't start turning and will sometimes make a screeching sound.

Why does this happen, and what can I do to prevent it?

[image]

Comment: What research have you done so far? The answer seems quite trivial if you take the motor apart - looks for 'dc toy motor teardown'.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're deforming the motor enough that either the sleeve bearings for the shaft bind on the shaft, or the stator magnets are physically contacting the rotor.

[image]

Maybe try /not/ squeezing the motor so hard?

Comment: To answer the second half of the question: either don't squeeze so hard or don't use such a cheap piece-of-**** motor.

Comment: If you were restricted to only this motor you may have to make some sort of housing for it if it needs to be held tightly for whatever reason. I woukd imagine it would probably be cheaper to buy a sturdier motor.